# How to solve frequent garbage collection in android?

Tags: android, android-memory, android-profiler

Our team is stuck in the problem, our android **application lags** after using some time, and here is the **Android Profiler** for the memory.

[image: Here is the image for Android Profiler]

I am noticing that the ***garbage collection is too frequent*** and I resolved almost every memory leak for our application.

Points to remember:

- Is this caused due to any module or library??
- Using too many images in nested recycler views like Playstore.
- Using AutoScrollViewPager with 1.5 secs of delay
- Using image library Glide for loading image in whole application.

This is happening after some seconds in verbose logs:

> 2022-03-15 16:37:47.761 30333-30358/com.app I/com.app: Background concurrent copying GC freed 417454(8609KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(328KB) LOS objects, 27% free, 16MB/22MB, paused 241us total 153.080ms
>
> 2022-03-15 16:37:51.226 30333-30358/com.app I/com.app: Background
> young concurrent copying GC freed 330919(6815KB) AllocSpace objects,
> 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 14MB/20MB, paused 685us total 129.321ms
>
> 2022-03-15 16:37:51.580 30333-30358/com.app I/com.app: Background
> concurrent copying GC freed 520664(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(132KB)
> LOS objects, 31% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 131us total 165.951ms
>
> 2022-03-15 16:37:58.195 30333-30358/com.app I/com.app: Background
> concurrent copying GC freed 391436(8248KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(68KB)
> LOS objects, 26% free, 16MB/22MB, paused 426us total 239.756ms

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to reuse already created objects instead of create new ones so often, this will reduce GC a lot.

Comment: @emandt I added some new modules and libraries to my project, previously everything is working fine. Do you have any idea why it's happening?

Comment: This library could call/force (bad thing!) a GC itself or could create a lot of Objects that Java marks as "unused" after a very shot time. You can view Memory Dump in your Profiler to check what Objects are in memory and recognize the Source of this issue.

Comment: I optimized some code and reduces the instances but still same issue exists

Comment: If the issue started from when you added that library, than there could be nothing you can do to fix it. It could be a library bug or it could be a library made by "bad developers" :) Try using a newer/older version of this library and check the results.

Comment: I update the question with logs, where this verbose logs are coming after every 2 seconds.

Comment: You still answer saying what happens.....but until you Debug the issue we cannot say you something more. You already said GC occurs often, so knowing it happens every 2 seconds, every 100ms or every 10 seconds is useless. It seems memory allocation occurs in "Native" (JNI), so there are some Native Code that creates a lot of objects which no-one seems to use, so them are garbaged quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some R&D and doing work on suggestions, Our app is 50-70% (Depending on RAM on different devices) performing better as per before.

I raised some points for the issue, I configure that:

- **Is this caused due to any module or library??**

Some modules make our APK size a little bit large at the time of debugging. So, if we apply progaurd or use bundle then our app APK will become less in size and will also take less RAM at that time.

- **Using too many images in nested recycler views like Playstore.**

Use the famous libraries for image loadings like glide or Picasso,
we need bitmap pooling for images which we are using again and again.
This will help us to avoid more and more bitmaps for the same image URLs

Reference: [Here is the good guidance, how to optimize recycler view](https://blog.mindorks.com/recyclerview-optimization)

- **Using AutoScrollViewPager with 1.5 secs of delay**

Here is the major issue that comes, after using the app for 3-5 mins, GC calls so frequently, and that is due to `ViewPager.setCurrentItem()`. For the whole application where we are using **ViewPager** and changing pages GC calls.

In AutoScrollViewPager there is a delay with 1.5 secs and then ViewPager AutoScrolls, then GC calls. That's why there are too many GCs in the android profiler after every 2 secs.

So, we removed the code for AutoScrolling, performance is better from the last scenario.

**Some other optimizations are:**

- Replaces multiple instances to singleton instances.
- Removed all Leaks from the application.

Reference: [Here is about Memory Leaks in Android](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4690472-memory-leaks-in-android)

Any suggestions for this issue will be helpful for all.
Thank you